# Change the device orientation from portrait to landscape on a button click in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have been trying to change the device orientation on a button click event for 2 days but I am not able to achieve it properly.

So, I have an iPhone app with a minimum version of 12.4, and the device that I am using to test is 14.4. I have used the code mentioned in this project [here](https://mnawazishabbas.medium.com/rotate-orientation-programmatically-in-swift-05-9f90c650b251) (which works properly when presenting a new view controller using push or present) but the same doesn't work when on the same view controller. The user needs to rotate his/her device to initiate the orientation change.

This is the code that I have in the view controller that I am trying to rotate on a button click event.

```
    let appDelegate = AppDelegate.sharedInstance
    let oldOrientaion = appDelegate.deviceOrientation
    appDelegate.deviceOrientation = oldOrientaion == .landscapeRight ? .portrait : .landscapeRight
    let value = appDelegate.deviceOrientation.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

Can someone please help me in figuring out what exactly is missing from this?

Also, on a side note, the view controller is presented on a different view controller so even if I try to present a new view controller like in the project for some time and change the orientation there it doesn't work.

Edit:

This is fixed now. I was trying to use the `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` to set the orientation instead of `UIInterfaceOrientation`. So changing the code to use `UIInterfaceOrientation` at the end works properly now.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing everything correctly, just need to call the `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` method to the oration change to take effect. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621400-attemptrotationtodeviceorientati):

> Some view controllers may want to use app-specific conditions to
> determine what interface orientations are supported. If your view
> controller does this, when those conditions change, your app should
> call this class method. The system immediately attempts to rotate to
> the new orientation.

In your code it will look like:

```
UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```